# angularJS $stateProvider - resolve $scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to resolve $scope for component-usage reasons but it seems to be a problem... please look at the code and let me know if you see a problem or have a different idea of how to implement it.

```
angular.module('app').config(
    function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                '': {
                    template: `<my-comp user-logged-in="userModel"></my-comp>`
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                '$scope': function ($rootScope) {
                    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
                    scope.userModel = {userId:1, name:'user'};
                    return scope;
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass the **userModel**'s data directly to the component controller, but it fails...

Currently I'm using the following logic which work's fine but i'm trying something new :)

```
views: {
    '': {
        template: `<my-comp user-logged-in="$ctrl.userModel"></my-comp>`,
        controller: function (userLoggedIn) {
            this.userModel = userLoggedIn;
        },
        controllerAs: '$ctrl'
    }
},
resolve: {
    userLoggedIn: function (userLoggedIn) {
        return userLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: why you wanted to pass whole scope to component, I'd say pass relevant data to component via resolve..

Comment: @PankajParkar I'm not, I'm trying to pass the userModel. the $scope is for the state controller not the component controller.